# The code crashes on line 45 "pthread_cond_signal"

Tags: c++, pthreads

```cpp
#include<pthread.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>

#define THREAD_NUM 2
using namespace std;


typedef struct
{
    pthread_cond_t cond[2];
    pthread_mutex_t mutex[2];
    pthread_t threads[THREAD_NUM];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int isA ;
    int isB ;
    int ismain;
} stThread;


void* func1( void* p )
{
    stThread* params = ( stThread* )p;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &params->mutex[0] );
    params->ismain = 1;
    while ( params->isA == 0 )
    {
        cout << "func1 is running" << endl;
        pthread_cond_signal( &params->cond[0] );
        pthread_cond_wait( &params->cond[1], &params->mutex[0] );
        params->isB = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal( &params->cond[1] );
    }
    cout << "func1 end" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &params->mutex[0] );
    pthread_exit( NULL );
    return NULL;
}

void* func2( void* p )
{
    stThread* params = ( stThread* )p;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &params->mutex[1] );

    params->isA = 1;
    while ( params->isB == 0 )
    {
        cout << "func2 is running" << endl;
        pthread_cond_signal( &params->cond[0] );
        pthread_cond_wait( &params->cond[1], &params->mutex[1] );
    }
    cout << "func2 end" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &params->mutex[1] );
    pthread_exit( NULL );
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    stThread p;
    p.isA = 0;
    p.isB = 0;
    p.ismain = 0;
    stThread* params = &p;

    pthread_mutex_init( &params->mutex[0], NULL );
    pthread_mutex_init( &params->mutex[1], NULL );
    pthread_attr_init( &params->attr );
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate( &params->attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED );
    pthread_cond_init( &params->cond[0], NULL );
    pthread_cond_init( &params->cond[1], NULL );


    pthread_mutex_lock( &params->mutex[0] );
    pthread_mutex_lock( &params->mutex[1] );
    pthread_create( &params->threads[0], &params->attr, func1, ( void* )( params ) );
    pthread_create( &params->threads[1], &params->attr, func2, ( void* )( params ) );
    while ( params->ismain == 0 )
    {
        pthread_cond_wait( &params->cond[0], &params->mutex[0] );
        //pthread_cond_wait( &params->cond[1], &params->mutex[1] );
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &params->mutex[0] );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &params->mutex[1] );

    cout << "end" << endl;

    pthread_attr_destroy( &params->attr );
    pthread_cond_destroy( &params->cond[0] );
    pthread_cond_destroy( &params->cond[1] );
    pthread_mutex_destroy( &params->mutex[0] );
    pthread_mutex_destroy( &params->mutex[1] );

    //pthread_exit( NULL );
    return 0;
}
```

I want to implement a function where the main function creates two detach threads, func1 and func2, respectively, but let func1 execute first and go to wait, then func2 and change the loop variable in func1. When func1 is awakened, func2 goes to wait. Finally func1 modifies the cyclic condition of func2 and awakens func2.

However, the code always crash in func2 when running `pthread_cond_signal( &params->cond[0] );`

```
    while ( params->isB == 0 )
    {
        cout << "func2 is running" << endl;
        pthread_cond_signal( &params->cond[0] );
        pthread_cond_wait( &params->cond[1], &params->mutex[1] );
    }
```

Why the code crash in `pthread_cond_signal`?

Comment: Don't use the C tag on C++ code.  It'll earn you downvotes rather than plaudits.

Comment: Which line is 45?

Comment: What does the crash say?

Comment: `&params->cond[1], &params->mutex[0]` - look at this carefully. The flow is broken, `main` exits, `params` is destroyed, the alive threads crash.

Comment: Do you know C++ has [std::thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), std::mutex, std::unique_lock, [std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)? So you don't need to use pthreads and get help from RAII behavior (automatic unlock of mutex when out of scope). Also note condition variables can have spurious wakeups, and you should always use std::condition_variable wait  with a predicate

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in the code presented.  Among them are:

- the initial thread, running in `main()`, locks both mutexes before launching the other two threads.  When it waits on CV 0 using mutex 0, it will release mutex 0, but **it will continue to hold mutex 1 locked**.  That will prevent the thread running `func2()` from acquiring it until after the initial thread breaks from its wait loop and unlocks the mutex, just before it tears down the mutexes and CVs and terminates.

  I haven't quite identified the sequence of events that permits `func2()` to reach its `pthread_cond_signal()` call at all, but if it does, it must at that point be racing with the initial thread to signal that CV before the initial thread destroys it (and before its lifetime ends; see below).
- the code appears to be relying on the threads to modify the `params` to signal the initial thread that it can clean up and finish, but

  - that is done by `func1()` *before* it is ready for the mutexes and CVs to be cleaned up
  - it would be far more conventional for the initial thread to *join* the other two to await their termination, but it can't do that because those have been detached
  - yet it doesn't make sense to detach the two additional threads, because they rely on the `params` object, whose lifetime is limited to the execution of `main()` by the initial thread.
- Your program contains data races, on account of the various threads not consistently using the same mutexes to protect the same objects.  It's not sufficient for a thread to lock just any mutex before accessing a given shared object.  All threads that ever access that object must hold *the same* mutex locked when they do so.
- You probably have too many mutexes, then -- I see no reason for more than one -- and you may have too many CVs.  You can use the same mutex in conjunction with multiple CVs, and that's sometimes appropriate.  You can also use the same CV for multiple, related purposes, and that's sometimes reasonable; typically, this requires broadcasting to them instead of signaling them.
- Not an error *per se*, but calling `pthread_exit(NULL)` is redundant with returning `NULL` from a thread's entry-point function.